# How Can I make this touch Slider move atomically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make this touch slider, which move between slides automatically.

I tried many ways but nothing helped, this bellow is my Code:

```css
.slider-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  transform: translateX(0);
  will-change: transform;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  cursor: grab;
}
  
.slide{
  max-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="pics/slider/127616685-multi-colored-samples-of-marble-granite-and-travertine-chips-and-pebbles-for-landscape-design-close-.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="pics/slider/1554689647283.jpg"/>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Well, could you add snippet as we can see what's your problem?

Comment: Full code
https://codepen.io/karim-abd-el-hameed/pen/mdmzmWL

Comment: I want slides to move automatically

Comment: What automatically? like marquees? Or initially slide to nth img? Please let me know what did you try for it and how is it not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this code at the bottom of your JS code.

This code changes the value of `currentTranslate` every 1 second and then calls the `touchEnd();` function.

**I added the variable "loop" if the value is `true` when the last slide is reached... the script will call the first one again and so on indefinitely. If it has a value of `false` when the last slide is reached, the interval will be removed. And scrolling the slides will stop.

```js
    var loop = true; //<-- "true" Loop  or "false" Stop on the End

    var slideShw = setInterval(() => {
        currentTranslate = currentTranslate - 101;
        touchEnd();
        if (currentIndex === slides.length - 1) {
            if (loop) {
                currentIndex -= slides.length;
            } else {
                stop_slideShw();
            }
        }
    }, 1000);

    function stop_slideShw() {
        clearInterval(slideShw);
    }
```

Example:

```js
    
// get our elements
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider-container'),
    slides = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.slide'))

// set up our state
let isDragging = false,
    startPos = 0,
    currentTranslate = 0,
    prevTranslate = 0,
    animationID,
    currentIndex = 0


// add our event listeners
slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
    const slideImage = slide.querySelector('img')
    // disable default image drag
    slideImage.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => e.preventDefault())
    // touch events
    slide.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart(index))
    slide.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd)
    slide.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove)
    // mouse events
    slide.addEventListener('mousedown', touchStart(index))
    slide.addEventListener('mouseup', touchEnd)
    slide.addEventListener('mousemove', touchMove)
    slide.addEventListener('mouseleave', touchEnd)
})

// make responsive to viewport changes
window.addEventListener('resize', setPositionByIndex)

// // prevent menu popup on long press 
// window.oncontextmenu = function (event) {
//   event.preventDefault()
//   event.stopPropagation()
//   return false
// }

function getPositionX(event) {
    return event.type.includes('mouse') ? event.pageX : event.touches[0].clientX
}

// use a HOF so we have index in a closure

function touchStart(index) {
    return function (event) {
        currentIndex = index
        startPos = getPositionX(event)
        isDragging = true
        animationID = requestAnimationFrame(animation)
        slider.classList.add('grabbing')
    }
}

function touchMove(event) {
    if (isDragging) {
        const currentPosition = getPositionX(event)
        currentTranslate = prevTranslate + currentPosition - startPos
    }
}

var movedBy;
function touchEnd() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(animationID)
    isDragging = false
    movedBy = currentTranslate - prevTranslate

    // if moved enough negative then snap to next slide if there is one
    if (movedBy < -100 && currentIndex < slides.length - 1) currentIndex += 1

    // if moved enough positive then snap to previous slide if there is one
    if (movedBy > 100 && currentIndex > 0) currentIndex -= 1

    setPositionByIndex()

    slider.classList.remove('grabbing')
}

function animation() {
    setSliderPosition()
    if (isDragging) requestAnimationFrame(animation)
}

function setPositionByIndex() {
    currentTranslate = currentIndex * -window.innerWidth
    prevTranslate = currentTranslate
    setSliderPosition()
}

function setSliderPosition() {
    slider.style.transform = `translateX(${currentTranslate}px)`
}

// NEW LINES /////////////////////////////////////////
var loop = true; //<-- "true" Loop or "false" Stop on the End

var slideShw = setInterval(() => {
    currentTranslate = currentTranslate - 101;
    touchEnd();
    if (currentIndex === slides.length - 1) {
        if (loop) {
            currentIndex -= slides.length;
        } else {
            stop_slideShw();
        }
    }
}, 1000);

function stop_slideShw() {
    clearInterval(slideShw);
}
```

```css
/* :root {
--shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}

* {
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
*/


.slider-container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    transform: translateX(0);
    will-change: transform;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
    cursor: grab;
}

.slide {
    max-height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1rem;
}

@media(min-width: 1200px) {
    .slide {
        padding: 3rem;
    }
}

.slide img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 50px -1px var(--shadow);
    border-radius: 4px;
    user-select: none;
}

.grabbing {
    cursor: grabbing;
}

.grabbing .slide img {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 40px -1px var(--shadow);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slide">
        <img
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/145939/pexels-photo-145939.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/47547/squirrel-animal-cute-rodents-47547.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img
            src="https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fspecials-images.forbesimg.com%2Fimageserve%2F5faad4255239c9448d6c7bcd%2FBest-Animal-Photos-Contest--Close-Up-Of-baby-monkey%2F960x0.jpg%3Ffit%3Dscale" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But if I want it to go in a loop
Means When reaches the last image, start over with the first one and so on . what should I do to do that?

Comment: I made a change in the code, please take a look. If my post is useful to you, you can mark it as Accepted Answer.

Comment: @Karim Abdlehameed, If my post is useful to you, you can mark it as Accepted Answer

Comment: I did sorry to be late @54ka

Answer (score 0):

To move your slider automatically you should use the animation property.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to work on slider without Javascript. I am giving some fresh codes, you can check them and rewrite your codes accordingly.

```js
var photos = ["1.png","2.png","3.png"]
var time = 3000;
var imgTag = document.querySelector("img")

var count = 0;

function changeImg() {
    document.slide.src = photos[count];
    count++;
    if(count==3){
        count=0;
        imgTag.src = photos[count];
    }
    else{
        imgTag.src = photos[count];
    }
    console.log("lap");
    setTimeout("changeImg()",time);
}

window.onload = changeImg;

function next(){
    count++;
    time=3000;
    if(count==3){
        count=0;
        imgTag.src = photos[count];
    }
    else{
        imgTag.src = photos[count];
    }
    console.log("next");
}

function prev(){
    count--;
    time=3000;
    if(count==-1){
        count=2;
        imgTag.src = photos[count];
    }
    else{
        imgTag.src = photos[count];
    }
    
    console.log("prev");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="prev()">Prev</button>
    <img src="1.png" name="slide" alt="" height="300" width="300">
    <button onclick="next()">Next</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Put any 3 images named "1.png" "2.png" "3.png". And then run the code. Hopefully it will run, and you will get an idea. Here I have used a setTimeout function that will fire up after 3 seconds to change your slides.

Thank you.